# nginx Unable to issue letsencrypt ssl certificate with Laravel Forge

Tags: laravel, nginx, ssl, lets-encrypt, laravel-forge

I have a Laravel project deployed with Laravel Forge in nginx.
This application has several aliases.
I am trying to issue ssl certificates for each aliases, but I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Challenge is invalid! (returned: invalid) (result: ["type"]  "http-01"
["status"]  "invalid"
["error","type"]    "urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized"
["error","detail"]  "Invalid response from example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx [xxx.xx.xxx.xx]: \"\u003c!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \\\"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\\\" \\\"DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\\\"\u003e\\n\u003chtml xmlns=\\\"http://www.w3.org/199\""
["error","status"]  403
["error"]   {"type":"urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized","detail":"Invalid response from example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx [xxx.xx.xxx.xx]: \"\u003c!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \\\"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\\\" \\\"DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\\\"\u003e\\n\u003chtml xmlns=\\\"http://www.w3.org/199\"","status":403}
["url"] "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/chall-v3/xxxxxxx/xxxxxx"
["token"]   "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
["validationRecord",0,"url"]    "example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
["validationRecord",0,"hostname"]   "example.com"
["validationRecord",0,"port"]   "80"
["validationRecord",0,"addressesResolved",0]    "xxx.xx.xxx.xx"
["validationRecord",0,"addressesResolved"]  ["xxx.xx.xxx.xx"]
["validationRecord",0,"addressUsed"]    "xxx.xx.xxx.xx"
["validationRecord",0]  {"url":"example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","hostname":"example.com","port":"80","addressesResolved": 
["xxx.xx.xxx.xx"],"addressUsed":"xxx.xx.xxx.xx"}
["validationRecord"]    [{"url":"example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","hostname":"example.com","port":"80","addressesResolved":["xxx.xx.xxx.xx"],"addressUsed":"xxx.xx.xxx.xx"}])
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's encrypt says that must send request via http (port 80), but cannot do it.
Try this:
Go to larave Forge site page, at the bottom, and edit nginx config file in this way:

```
listen: 80
listen:[::] 80
```

Save and try again to issue your certificates.

Remember that after this, you must modify the configuration to allow https communications.

It worked for me.